Restrict app access from Facebook Developer Account
I have created an app on the Facebook developer account and I'm using those details to implement Facebook login in my react-native app. Are there any settings available on the Facebook Developer Account where I can allow login specifically only for my  react-native app E.g. by specifying my package name so that the login works only for the app with that package name.
